# Generate random numbers with equal probabilities in c++

Tags: c++, random

For example,
array of pairs of ranges
p={[23, 28], [11, 14], [31, 39]}

You have to return random number such that this number should be:

1. In any one of these pairs
2. Each number in these ranges should have equal probability of being chosen.

I can easily generate a random number that lies between any of these intervals like

```
int x=(rand()%(p[i].second-p[i].first) )+ p[i].first;
```

How can I generate a random number that can lie in any interval in the array and that too with equal probability.

Comment: Is the probability of the number being in each range 1/3 ?

Comment: [Uniformly](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) pick a random number that is in the range `[0, number_of_sets)`, then use that number to pick the range in that index and then use its range to uniformly pick a value in `[range_start, range_end]`

Comment: Suppose my input is `p = {[1, 99], [100, 100]}`. Should I pick `100` with probability `0.01` (there are 100 valid numbers, 100 is 1 of them) or probability `0.5` (there are two intervals, if I pick the second interval I pick 100 every time)? Your description of requirement 2 makes me think it's the former, which means you can't do the two-step approach.

Comment: @NathanOliver: That can create nasty effects with some generators. Personally I'd build the quantile function and feed that a uniform drawing in [0, 1).

Comment: @Bathsheba No it would depend on the total number of elements . In this example the probabilities of  each range would be 23-28=6/19 14-11=4/19   39-31=9/19 .

Comment: Another option then would be to build a [`std::discrete_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution) but that would involve a lot of work to compute the probabilities for all numbers in the range `[lowest_range_start, highest_range_end]`

Comment: Can we assume that those ranges don't overlap?

Answer (score 3):

Draw a number uniformly in the range [0, 18].

Add 11.

If that number is 15 or more then add 8.

If that number is 29 or more then add 2.

This method has the advantage that it uses only one drawing. Using multiple drawings can cause the statistical properties of the random numbers to deteriorate depending on the properties of the underlying generator. Sampling with rejection can cause issues with some low discrepancy sequences such as Sobol.

Comment: Could you add how you computed these magic numbers?

Comment: Yes, please. Elaborate a bit on the numbers.

Comment: @SynAck Does it click if the answer began *Draw a number in the range [11, 29]* without saying *Add 11*?

Comment: @SynAck: Play around with it in Excel - it will become obvious then.

Comment: It might also click if you were to try this on paper: Consider if you draw 0. What is the resulting number? (It's 11). OK, what if you draw 1. What is the resulting number? Keep considering all the possible numbers you might draw, up thru 18. Note that in each case you get one of the values in those ranges.

Comment: Thank you. Will try this in a while. If I get it, I will accept the answer :)

Comment: Breaking down the steps. 1.) Figure out how many total numbers are valid outputs. 2.) Uniformly randomly select one of those numbers. 3.) Figure out which of the original ranges this would be drawn from. 4.) Figure out which element of the range this should be. Steps 3 and 4 require some bookkeeping.

Comment: @SynAck: Better still, when it does click, answer this question yourself perhaps more clearly than me - I'll be sure to upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

We could follow a common approach by defining a specialized generator class.

We can overload its () function call operator, so once we have an object of that class, we just get a variate thru `variate = genObj()`. Underneath, the class is to call standard C++11 (and beyond) random number generation facilities, as exposed for example in the [ISO C++ N3551 paper](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n3551.pdf).

Note that `rand()` and `srand()` are *legacy* C facilities.

In this example, there are 19 possible variates. We number them from 0 to 18. First, we generate uniformly a random integer in [0..18]. This is called the *rank*. Second, from the rank we compute the actual variate; this second step is known as *unranking*.

The generator class has a `drawRank()` method which returns a rank.

We define the *cumulants* of the range set as, for each range, the size of that range plus the sum of the sizes of all ranges before itself.

Once we have determined that the variate for a certain rank lies in the i-th range, unranking can be done like this:

```
variate = if (i == 0)  then  ranges[0].lowerBound + rank
                       else  ranges[i].lowerBound + (rank - cumulants[i-1])
```

**Side note:** as here the ranges are quite small, instead we could unrank with just a simple vector used as a lookup table, translating ranks to variates directly. But if some ranges become large, like [1000000,199999], this approach obviously becomes a memory wasting one.

So we can now proceed to write our specialized generator class.

First, the **public part**, with the `#include` clauses and the constructor:

```
#include  <cstdlib>
#include  <map>
#include  <random>
#include  <iostream>

using Ranges = std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>;

class RangesGen
{
public:
   // Constructor:
   RangesGen(int randomSeed_, const Ranges& ranges_) :
       randomSeed(randomSeed_), ranges(ranges_),
       engine(randomSeed_), ud(0, getTotalCount(ranges_)-1),
       totalCount(getTotalCount(ranges_)),
       lengths(), cumulants()
   {
       for (auto p: ranges) {
           lengths.push_back(1 + p.second - p.first);
           cumulants.push_back(0);  // just to fill it up
       }
       cumulants[0] = lengths[0];
       for (int i=1; i < lengths.size(); i++)
           cumulants[i] = cumulants[i-1] + lengths[i];
   }
```

The overloaded function call operator, with the unranking logic, is also in the public part of the class:

```
    // return a random variate:
    int operator()()
    {
        int  rank = drawRank();
        int     i = 0;
        while (cumulants[i] <= rank)
            i++;
        // here  rank < cum[i] - so rank fits in the i-th range
        // unranking logic :
        if (i==0)  
            return (ranges[0].first + rank);
        else
            return ( ranges[i].first + (rank - cumulants[i-1]) );
    }
```

Second, the **private part**, with the actual list of fields and the `drawRank()` private method:

```
private:
    int                                 randomSeed;
    std::mt19937                        engine;  // raw random number generator
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int>  ud;
    Ranges                              ranges;
    int                                 totalCount;
    bool                                verbose;
    std::vector<int>                    lengths;
    std::vector<int>                    cumulants;

    static int getTotalCount(const Ranges& ranges)
    {
        int   total = 0;
        for (auto p: ranges)
            total += 1 + p.second - p.first;
        return total;
    }

    int drawRank()
    {
        return ud(engine);
    }
};
```

### Test program:

We can write a small test program, which generates 19*2,000,000 = 38 millions variates, and then computes the corresponding histogram. As this is supposed to be an uniform distribution, we expect each variate to get close to 2 millions instances.

```
int main()
{
    Ranges  myRanges {{23, 28}, {11, 14}, {31, 39}};
    int   randomSeed {424344};
    RangesGen  gen1(randomSeed, myRanges);  // specialized variate generator

    std::map<int,int>  histogram{};  // empty map

    for (int j=0; j < 19*2000000; j++) {
        int  variate = gen1();
        if (histogram.end() == histogram.find(variate))
            histogram[variate] = 0;  // First sight of this variate, insert it.
        int prevCount = histogram[variate];
        histogram[variate] = prevCount + 1;
    }

    // display histogram contents:
    for (auto itr = histogram.begin(); itr != histogram.end(); ++itr) {
        int variate = itr->first;
        int count   = itr->second;
        std::cout << count << " instances of variate " << variate <<'\n';
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

### Test program output:

```
2001500 instances of variate 11
1999233 instances of variate 12
1999842 instances of variate 13
1999205 instances of variate 14
1999467 instances of variate 23
1999725 instances of variate 24
2001476 instances of variate 25
1999592 instances of variate 26
2001036 instances of variate 27
2002098 instances of variate 28
2000420 instances of variate 31
2000231 instances of variate 32
2000569 instances of variate 33
1996539 instances of variate 34
2000371 instances of variate 35
1999316 instances of variate 36
2000151 instances of variate 37
1998338 instances of variate 38
2000891 instances of variate 39
```

So the histogram is as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Generally, you shouldn't use rand and scale by division, because it can lead to some numbers being generated more commonly. There is a very good talk about this ['rand Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) from MSDN a few years ago. In modern C++ you should probably use the random distribution methods brought in in C++11 in the `<random>` header. For e.g.:

```
std::mt19937 generator(0); // Use mersenne twister algorithm with seed 0 - shouldn't use same seed repeatedly but generate this in some way

// set up a uniform distribution:
std::uniform_int_distribution<> distribution(23, 28);

// generate a random number in that range
distribution(generator)
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question at all.